# Looking for a gem that simplifies rewriting in Rails

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems

I read about a gem months ago that implements a simple DSL to make it easy to handle the complex rerouting operations, similar to the .htaccess file in Apache. But I can't remember what it was called, and haven't bookmarked it unfortunately.

Does anyone know what I'm talking about?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it! I believe [this was the one](https://github.com/jtrupiano/rack-rewrite).